# what's unclick event function in JQuery

Tags: jquery, events, click

I use a text box and I want when user click to Textbox then Run some codes

```
$("#Textbox").click(function() {
   // Do Some Codes
})
```

and when user unclick from Textbox or clicked to others Tags or Fields then show alert to screen, I used unclick function but it don't true

```
$("#Textbox").unclick(function() {
   // Do Some Codes
})
```

How to fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by unclick.... do you mean blur

Comment: my mean is that when user clicked to others Tags or Fields

Comment: there should be an unclick that does the reverse of every operation performed in the click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#Textbox").blur(function() {
   // Do Some Codes
})
```

There is a blur method which trigger when lose the focus; try it

Comment: Thanks @Red Wolf's Husband

Answer (score 0):

There is no `unclick` function in Jquery. You mean `unbind("click")`

```
$("#othertagsselector").focus(function() {
   alert('focused');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he mean to handle `keyUp` or a mouse release after a click (`mouseUp`) event.

like

```
 $( "#TextBox" ).keyup(function() {
  // check for a specific key 
});
```

or

```
$( "#TextBox" ).mouseup(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .mouseup() called." );
});
```

I guess I am wrong, though ...!

Answer (score 0):

To focus the textbox you can use either

```
$("#Textbox").click(function() {
  // Do Some Codes
});
```

or

```
 $("#Textbox").focus(function() {
   // Do Some Codes
 });
```

And to leave the textbox you can use the

```
 $("#Textbox").focusout(function() {
    // Do Some Codes
 });
```

or

```
 $("#Textbox").blur(function() {
    // Do Some Codes
 });
```